# jQuery onmouseover + onmouseout / hover on two different divs

Tags: jquery, html, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've got a Problem:

Here a part of my HTML:

```
<div id="div_1">
    Here Hover
</div>
<div id="div_2">
    Here content to show
</div>
```

And here a part of my jQuery Script:

```
jQuery('#div_2').hide();
jQuery('#div_1').onmouseover(function() {
    jQuery('#div_2').fadeIn();
}).onmouseout(function(){
    jQuery('#div_2').fadeOut();
});
```

The Problem:

If i hover on the div_1, the div_2 is shown, if i hover out, the div_2 is hidden, but:

If i hover first on div_1 and then go over div_2, the div_2 is hidden fast.

I've tried this with jQuery.addClass(); after mouseout in div_1, but nothing is changing.

I dont want do make the second div in the first div... Is there another way with jQuery?

Thx Ahmet

Comment: To start you off, you need to lose the `on` prefix to the mouseover/mouseout event handlers. It's just `jQuery('#div_1').mouseover(function(){...`

Comment: this was a mini copy error^^thx

Comment: By the way, you should use the `hover` shorthand to add the handlers

Answer (score 14):

Here's another approach, just apply the hover to the second div as well so it stops itself being hidden:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div_2').hide();
  $('#div_1, #div_2').hover(function() {
      $('#div_2').stop().fadeIn();
  }, function(){
      $('#div_2').stop().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: When I have done this in the past, it can leave subsequent fade-in events fading to only partial opacity. Instead, I use http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ which lets me specify 0 and 1 for the opacity.

Answer (score 2):

The mouseleave function might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to put both `<div>`s inside a third container `<div>`, then apply the hover effect to the container `<div>`.

By the way, you should use the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) shorthand to add the handlers.

Comment: There are more then 1 Div wich are showing different content in the other div, on mouse over, (ajax) so i try to just work with one div

Answer (score 0):

Try using hover() instead of mouseover() and mouseout().

Check out this documentation page : http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the mouseover handler to `#div_1`, and the mouseout handler to `#div_2`. This way, `#div_2` is shown when you mouseover `#div_1`, and it is hidden when you mouseout of `#div_2` (instead of as soon as you mouseout of `#div_1`). The only real drawback to this is that in order to hide the second div, you must mouseover it first.

Something like this:

```
jQuery('#div_2').hide();
jQuery('#div_1').mouseover(function() {
    jQuery('#div_2').fadeIn();
});
jQuery('#div_2').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery('#div_2').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery('#div_2').hide();
    jQuery('#div_1').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery('#div_2').fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery('#div_2').mouseout(function(){
        jQuery('#div_2').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: good idea, dont thought about that :-) If I need it again, I can try this :-) thanks!